# How to use the PowerManager and PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK

Tags: android

I develop a small app, this one have to run always over all when the device is sleep or deep sleep (press right button to turn off the screen) I read many posts about it, and all tell me that the way is use PowerManager, and my question is if I use fine this command, my structure is> myActivity.class, ReceiverBoot.class and ServiceBoot.class, I use the POwerManager class on myActivity.class like this:

```
PowerManager mgr = (PowerManager)this.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
PowerManager wakeLock = mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP , "MyWakeLock");
```

on onCreateMethod after of this one put

```
wakeLock.acquire();
```

and after of this one I have a

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
this.mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(
                new TimerTask(){
                    @Override
                    public void run(){doTask();}
                } , 0, 1000);

wakeLock.release();
```

on Manifest XML code I have

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

and on layout XML code have

```
android:keepScreenOn="true"
```

but after to 10seg the creen es OFF always but the app is running, jut with wifi.

the app work very fine with wifi conn, but when change to 3G conn, the app is gone, I use fine this command?? the problem is the kind of conn to Internet??? thanks a lot!

Comment: PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK doesn't lock the display on, just CPU. Also why are you releasing the lock after creating your task? Is that intended? What process are you expecting to happen?

Comment: thanks for comment, well, we need that when start the device the app run, that's fine, and we need that the app run always when the user press the button (turn off the screen) , the app have to run anyway, or if the user don't press nothing the screen never go to off. is good way my develop?, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm not 100% clear on your issue. Whether its the data issue, or the screen issue. (Or if the screen issue is what you are doing to try and fix the data issue?).

**For the screen**

You are not using the right lock to keep the screen on. `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` only requests that you can use the processor. To keep the screen on your app use one of `SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK`, `SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK` or `FULL_WAKE_LOCK` depending on what you want. This lock should be held for as long as you need the lock. Currently you are releasing it in onCreate(). Keep in mind that if the user presses the power button though that your lock is released (with PARTIAL being the exception to this).

If your intent is just to keep the screen on when a view is active then it's better not to use the lock at all. The wake lock needs an extra permission. You can do it by adding this to your `onCreate` override:

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

This is the same effect as using `android:keepScreenOn="true"`, which you already seem to be doing. I can't however tell why that isn't working from your snippets. Make sure you are inflating the right layout.

**For your data**

The device will likely be switching off 3G data when the screen is not active (and no lock is present). Again, don't release your lock if you need it (Though don't keep it forever either, that's just going to suck up phone battery).

Comment: Hi Andy, thanks so much for you answer, well, the app work, if I dont press the right button the screen not turn Off, also ii press the right button and the screen is Off the app continue running, this case on wifi network, the problem is when change to 3G network, I use the connect from other device (Iphone) connect with tablet (on this one is the app running), the app upload files from tablet to server, but while the mobile is on Office + 3G the app work fine, but when we are on street + 3G and same device, dont work, duo you have some idea? thanks a lot!