# Android Online Streaming Application should not be closed on screen locking and Unlocking

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity, streaming

I'm developing an online streaming application. I am facing an issue in my application.
When i am running my application and click on device lock hardware key , the application is closed. I want the application to get launched on the same activity i was before locking the device.

I want my application to stay active even if the device is locked.

Appreciate any solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**implement partial wake lock**

define

```
PowerManager.WakeLock wl;
```

oncreate

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
wl.acquire();
```

After oncreate

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    wl.release();
    }
}//End of onPause


@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    wl.acquire();
}//End of onResume
```

manifest permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use a `PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK` to ensure that your activity is kept active. `android.permission.WAKE_LOCK` must be requested in your manifest. However, battery will drain faster, so do remember to release the wakelock as soon as possible.

Use a service instead: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

[How to use the PowerManager and PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20657031/how-to-use-the-powermanager-and-partial-wake-lock)

Comment: I already given the '<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />' permission in the manifest. please let me know how to implement the 'PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK' sample code or useful link or something

Comment: check the edit and please accept and close the question if it was helpful